# typing.NamedTuple as type annonation for list does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I though I could specify a type for the elements of a list as follows:

```py
import typing

CustomType = typing.NamedTuple("CustomType", [("one", str), ("two", str)])


def test_function(some_list: list[CustomType]):
    print(some_list)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_list = list[
        CustomType(one="test", two="test2"),
        CustomType(one="Test", two="Test2")
    ]
    
    test_function(some_list=test_list)
```

But this warns me, at the test_function call that `Expected type 'list[CustomType]', got 'Type[list]' instead`.

The following will work, but I am not sure why it must be in this way:

```py
test_list: list[CustomType] = list([
    CustomType(one="test", two="test2"),
    CustomType(one="Test", two="Test2")
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem here is how you instanciate the list. `list[]` will give you a list type with some extra flavour. You want to instanciate the list with the classic syntax e.g. using simply brackets, or your more convoluted `list([...])`.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_list = [
        CustomType(one="test", two="test2"),
        CustomType(one="Test", two="Test2")
    ]
    
    test_function(some_list=test_list)
```